# Four-function calculator design

Tags: c++, beginner, calculator

I am new to C++ and am looking to expand my knowledge. Below is a simple program that I've made. I would like to know how it could be improved, in any way. The introduction of new ways to do things is what I am looking for. These could be anything from improving efficiency to validating input - just whatever you think is most important or beneficial.

```
float calculate(float x, char y, float z) {
    float answer;

    switch (y) {

        case '+':
            answer = x + z;
            break;

        case '-':
            answer = x - z;
            break;

        case '/':
            answer = x / z;
            break;

        case '*':
            answer = x * z;
            break;

        default:
            return(0);
    }

    cout <<"= "; return answer;
}

int main() {
    float num1;
    float num2;
    char aOp;

    cout << ">> "; 
    cin >> num1 >> aOp >> num2;
    cout << calculate(num1, aOp, num2) << endl << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Headers**.  Did you leave out the includes and function prototype at the top for simplicity or something?  If not, you need to put them here otherwise your program will not compile.
- **Function-returning and displaying**.  The last statement in your function along with the printing of the function's return value in `main()` *will* work, but it's not a good way to write it.

  Instead, move the `cout <<"= ";` from your function (just keep `return answer;`) to your `std::cout` statement in `main()`.
- **Function arguments/parameters**.  You may want to keep like-types together for clarity and so that you don't mismatch them, which would cause bugs.  Whichever order is easiest to remember.

  For instance, consider these:

  ```
  calculate(num1, num2, aOp);            // function call
  calculate(float x, float y, char z) {} // function definition
  ```
- **Early return in `switch`**.  Instead of having a local variable to update and return at the end, you could instead return from the respective `case`:

  ```
  switch (y) {
      case '+': return x + z;
      case '-': return x - z;
      case '/': return x / z;
      case '*': return x * z;
      default: std::logic_error("invalid operator"); // from <stdexcept>
  }
  ```

  Notice this `default` statement.  If the user enters an invalid operator, but no input validation was done beforehand, and exception will be thrown.  Overall, it's best to have a useful `default`, and this is one example.
- You should also make sure the user isn't dividing by 0.  If so, don't let the calculation take place, otherwise there will be problem.  For such a case, you can just terminate from `main()` early:

  ```
  if (num2 == 0 && aOp == '/')
  {
      std::cout << "You cannot divide by 0!  Terminating...";
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  ```